# How to correctly inherit from a parent component in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vue-class-components

I'm using Vue v2 with Typescript and I'm trying to extend a parent class:

My parent class is called `BaseSelect` and looks like this:

```
<template>
  <select :value="value" @change="$emit('change', $event.target.value)">
    <option value="">default option</option>
    <slot />
  </select>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Model, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({})
export default class BaseSelect extends Vue {
  @Model('change', { type: String, required: false, default: '' })
  private readonly value!: string

  private valid = true;

  validate(): boolean {
    this.valid = !!this.value;
    return this.valid;
  }
}
</script>
```

My child class `BaseSelectGender` looks like this:

```
<template>
  <base-select :value="value" @change="$emit('change', $event)">
    <option value="male">I'm male</option>
    <option value="female">I'm female</option>
  </base-select>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { BaseSelect } from '@/components/base';

@Component({
  components: { BaseSelect }
})
export default class BaseSelectGender extends BaseSelect {}
</script>
```

When I use `<base-select-gender>` in my code there are two instances of the `BaseSelect` component (and therefore two different instances of the `valid` variable):

1. The first instance which is created because of the inheritance
2. The second instance which is created because of the usage of `<base-select>` in the child

This leads to some problems when the `valid` variable changes because the wrong instance of the variable is reflected in the DOM.

So my question is now: How can I extend a base class and also use it or at least extend the html code in the template part of my child component?

Comment: Did you figure it out ? :)

Comment: @Boern yes, but it's only a workaround. I'll add it as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Workaround

So I found a workaround where I'm using the `ref` attribute to have access to the attributes and methods of the "inner" component (the one in the `template` section).

This allows me to manually synchronize all the attributes that I need (make sure that the required attributes do not have a `private` modifier).

My `BaseSelectGender` component now looks like this:

```
<template>
  <base-select 
    :value="value" 
    @change="$emit('change', $event)"
    v-bind="{ ...$attrs, ...$props }"
    ref="inner"
  >
    <option value="male">I'm male</option>
    <option value="female">I'm female</option>
  </base-select>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { BaseSelect } from '@/components/base';

@Component({
  components: { BaseSelect }
})
export default class BaseSelectGender extends BaseSelect {
  get inner() {
    return this.$refs.inner as BaseSelect;
  }

  setValid(valid: boolean) {
    this.valid = valid;
    this.inner.setValid(valid);
  }

  validate(): boolean {
    this.valid = this.inner.validate();
    return this.valid;
  }
}
</script>
```

**Pro-tip:** Use `v-bind="{ ...$attrs, ...$props }"` to pass through all the attributes and props from the outer component to the inner component.